# I'm running out of heap space while using Clojure, what do I do?

Tags: java, sqlite, clojure

I'm doing data analysis in Clojure. During the course of this data analysis I'm interacting with a SQlite file with about three hundred megabytes of data in it. Some queries on this dataset like

`(select crawls)`

return really long lists of crawling information. However, other queries that target larger columns are giving me:

> OutOfMemoryError Java heap space  org.sqlite.NativeDB.column_text
>   (NativeDB.java:-2)

I can get this with korma with something as simple as:

```
(select authors)
```

As will:

```
=> (first (select stories))
OutOfMemoryError Java heap space  org.sqlite.NativeDB.column_text (NativeDB.java:-2)
```

Does anyone know how I can go  about fixing this issue? This is my first large data analysis project.

Answer (score 4):

The queries should be returning a lazy result, so that you can work with the result without needing to have the whole thing in the heap. If you do a large select from the repl, the implicit print realizes the whole lazy seq all in one go, thus running out of heap.

The correct way to handle this is to write a `reduce` (or maybe a `map` / `doseq` combo) that will work with one result at a time without holding onto older elements. Watch out for "holding onto the head", that is, don't bind the top element of the lazy seq, or else the whole thing will be held in the heap.

Comment: I tried doing (take 10 (select authors)) and I still crashed. take, according to what I understand, won't realize the entire list.

Comment: How about `(first authors)` - are authors stored in such a way that they have nested data structures? You may need to access the keys inside one author in a lazy manner. How about `(keys (first authors))` ? Also, it may help to bump up your -Xmx arg to the jvm while you debug this issue: `:jvm-opts ["-Xmx4g"]` (or whatever is appropriate given your available physical memory) in your `project.clj` if using leinengen (which you should be).

Comment: They don't have nested structure. => (first (select stories))
OutOfMemoryError Java heap space  org.sqlite.NativeDB.column_text (NativeDB.java:-2)

Comment: Are you sure korma returns a lazy sequence: see => (type (select crawls))
clojure.lang.PersistentVector

Comment: Try to add (limit 1) to query

Comment: If korma does not return a lazy result, jdbc does.

Comment: Korma doesn't return lazy results.  Each query returns a vector (which is by definition fully realized)

Comment: In that case, if using korma is neccessary, an option would be using offset and limit parameters to avoid the query result smashing the heap.